# How to stop a class halfway, to run the next class, and how to do so?

Tags: python, class, call

I searched on the internet and couldn't find a solution. Please help. 
Let's say...

```
class A(self):
    def __init__ (self):
        """one chunk of code here"""

    if (condition met):
        print 'access granted'
        """I want to stop the code here and ask it to run class B, instead of just one method from class B"""
    else:
        print 'Stop process'
        break

class B(self):
    def __init__ (self):
        """one more chunk of codes here"""
```

Is this possible? (pardon my mess of codes)

Comment: You don't "run" a class. You run functions.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem, what is it you intend to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if condition code will run only once when you run that script. Whenever you create an instance of a class, only `__init__` function is run. As `interjay` mentioned, you don't run a class, you run functions.